# VSCode not showing proper params in object

Tags: visual-studio-code, jsdoc

I have jsdoc'ed my function like this:

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object} SearchTerms
 * @property {string} what
 * @property {string} where
 * @property {boolean} online
 */

/**
 * From react-router params, which are URL encoded, it figures out the "what", "where", and "online" terms.
 *
 * @export
 * @param {Object} params The `params` field from react-router component props.
 * @param {string} [params.what="Everything"] The subject of users search.
 * @param {string} [params.where] The location of users search.
 * @returns {SearchTerms}
 */
export function getSearchTerms(params)  {
```

However the `params` key is not properly expanded on hover of the function:

[image]

Is there anyway for it to properly expand `params` argument? I was hoping for it to show:

[image]

Except that it should also show that it is optional with question mark. And as I type the argument, it should show the description of that argument like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you've specified the type of your `params` param as `Object`.  You should break out your params as second `@typedef`:

```
/**
 * @typedef SearchOptions
 * @property {String} [what="Everything"] The thing
 * @property {String} [where] A place
 */

/**
 * @param {SearchOptions} params
 */
function getSearchTerms(params){ ... }
```

Using a named interface like this, VSCode should show the arguments in Intellisense like you're looking for.

Comment: I remember reading about this a few months ago, I believe the syntax you used (dot-separated sub-parameter names) is technically valid JSDoc, but not supported by the Typescript parser that populates Intellisense.  I don't love having to make up a type name for every "opts" argument but it gets the job done.

Comment: I so agree with you I didnt want to typedef for every opts arg. Thank you sir so much for explaining its the parser in vscode.

Comment: It seems like that doesn't do it either. SearchOptions still don't get expanded on as seen [here](https://imgur.com/Aalmr6j). Any ideas?

Comment: I see the confusion.  In the OP, they're taking an options-object as a parameter (what I called SearchOptions), and returning a results-object that they call SearchTerms. My answer doesn't show the return type, only the parameter (options) type.  So Intellisense will show autocomplete for the options object, but the implied return type of the function is `any`, so you won't get any autocomplete there.

Comment: To clarify: paste the code from my answer, then type `getSearchTerms({})`, put your cursor between the curly braces, and trigger autocomplete (`CTRL`+`Space`).  You should see `what` and `where` along with their descriptions.  Now, add a period after the close-paren and trigger autocomplete; you should see all global identifiers but no specific property hints, because the return type is `any`.